# How to get documents satisfying both the query terms using elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

Trying to frame work elastic query to get the documents which have both these queries fileds values , for example , i want documents or data which have country as 'india' and wealth as '12 or 10 or 09'

i tried to frame the query below but not getting the expected result

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "person_details",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            { "match": {"person_details.weath": "12"}},
            { "match": {"person_details.weath": "10"}},
            { "match": {"person_details.weath": "09"}}
          ]
        }
      },
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "person_details.country": "INDIA"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

so for example in the backend their are four persons with below details

```
person country  person wealth
 india            12
 japan            23
 india            10
 india            09
 US               12
```

then the formed elastic query must return 3 person details , but my framed query is returning 4 entries (returning US person details also ) , my query is not considering country condition strictly .

Any idea on this please  , got stuck with it .

---

update : Based on one answer of @paqash updated query

```
{
  query: {
    nested: {
      path: "product_vendors",
        query: {
            bool :{
                must : [
                    bool : {
                        should : [
                            { "match": {"product_vendors.manufacturer_style": "123"}},
                            { "match": {"product_vendors.manufacturer_style": "345"}}
                        ]
                    },
                    term : {
                        "product_vendors.id": "777"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

even tried below

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "product_vendors",
        "query": {
            "bool" :{
                "must" : [
                    "bool" : {
                        "should" : [
                            { "match": {"product_vendors.manufacturer_style": "123"}},
                            { "match": {"product_vendors.manufacturer_style": "345"}}
                        ]
                    },
                    "term" : {
                        "product_vendors.id": "777"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

getting below parsing error

{
  "message": "Bad Request: Invalid Json and exception is groovy.json.JsonException: expecting '}' or ',' but got current char 'q' with an int value of 113\n\nThe current character read is 'q' with an int value of 113\nexpecting '}' or ',' but got current char 'q' with an int value of 113\nline number 2\nindex number 4\n  query: {\n..^"
}

Answer (score 0):

You should have both query inside the bool query in a must clause. So replace:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "match": {"person_details.weath": "12"}},
        { "match": {"person_details.weath": "10"}},
        { "match": {"person_details.weath": "09"}}
      ]
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "person_details.country": "INDIA"
    }
  }
```

with:

```
query: {
 bool: {
  must: [
   bool: {
    should: [
        { "match": {"person_details.weath": "12"}},
        { "match": {"person_details.weath": "10"}},
        { "match": {"person_details.weath": "09"}}
      ]
   },
   term: {
      "person_details.country": "INDIA"
    }
  ]
 }
}
```

Comment: i tried what you suggest , but not getting the desired result .

Comment: What are you getting?

Comment: am getting the same result , as i mentioned in my query above .